# Windows 11 Research for a school projet

Tags: windows

I need help with a school task. Basically, I need to ask other developers their opinion about the new Windows 11 (qualities, flaws, etc.)

Thank you!

just a little review

Comment: This is not a topic you can ask about here, as this is subjective and likely leads to discussion. See [help/on-topic]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Different persons have different opinions , but you can checkout here
https://www.quora.com/What-is-your-review-on-newly-launched-Windows-11
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/windows-11-overview